# Remove duplicates from first column in Select (not Distinct) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, duplicates, distinct

I am new to Oracle.

I have a **Select** as part of a larger query which returns the below result. My problem is that for the first column I only need the first appearance of each value (they are sorted ascending). The result should look like what you get when you remove duplicates in Excel (a Distinct does not work here, I guess, as I still need the other rows separately).

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this ?

**My query (shortened):**

```
Select
   p.ID
   , p.SUB_ID
   , p.ITEM_NAME AS ITEM
   , p.ITEM_PRICE AS PRICE
   /* ... */
FROM
   PRICE_LIST p
WHERE
   /* ... */
GROUP BY
   p.ID
   , p.SUB_ID
   , p.ITEM_NAME
   , p.ITEM_PRICE
   /* ... */
ORDER BY
   p.ID, p.SUB_ID
```

**Current result:**

[image]

**Required result:**

[image]

Comment: I **think** you only need to GROUP BY p.ID and none of the others. But I am far from a SQ expert, so I am just stabbing in the dark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally this sort of formatting should be handled in your presentation layer.  That being said, we might be able to approximate what you want as follows:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ID, p.SUB_ID, p.ITEM_NAME AS ITEM, p.ITEM_PRICE AS PRICE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ID ORDER BY p.SUB_ID) rn
    FROM PRICE_LIST p
    WHERE
    /* ... */
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN TO_CHAR(t.ID) ELSE '' END AS ID,
    t.SUB_ID, t.ITEM, t.PRICE
FROM cte t
ORDER BY
    t.ID,
    t.SUB_ID
```

**Gordon's edit:**

We could just write this without a subquery/CTE at all, using `ROW_NUMBER()` directly in the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ID ORDER BY p.SUB_ID) = 1
         THEN TO_CHAR(p.ID) ELSE '' END AS ID,
    p.SUB_ID, p.ITEM_NAME AS ITEM, p.ITEM_PRICE AS PRICE
FROM PRICE_LIST p
WHERE
    /* ... */
ORDER BY
    p.ID,
    p.SUB_ID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim - this is perfect and exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Yes, still works, actually this was indeed required.

Comment: Tim . . . Assuming that `SELECT DISTINCT` is not really needed for the query, then the subquery/CTE is not necessary.  The `row_number()` can go directly in the `CASE`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Just to add here, your update made this the perfect solution for me. Works great and thanks for pointing it out ! :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thanks for adding Gordon's update - works great !

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
      DECODE(RN, 1, ID, '') AS ID
    , SUB_ID
    , ITEM
    , PRICE
    , RN 
FROM (
    Select
       p.ID
       , p.SUB_ID
       , p.ITEM_NAME AS ITEM
       , p.ITEM_PRICE AS PRICE
       /* ... */
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY P.ID ORDER BY P.SUB_ID) AS RN
    FROM
       PRICE_LIST p
    WHERE
       /* ... */
    GROUP BY
       p.ID
       , p.SUB_ID
       , p.ITEM_NAME
       , p.ITEM_PRICE
       /* ... */
    ORDER BY
       p.ID, p.SUB_ID
   )
```